# Como podría meter un fondo para toda la pantalla y que la imagen se superponga en ese mismo fondo?

Tags: html, css

**

### Codigo

**

Quiero que se inserte como fondo de pantalla un fondo negro y la imagen.png superpuesta a ese fondo.
He intentado esto pero no funciona..

```
   <style>

       body{
           background-color: darkorange;
           background-image: url(img/imagen.png);
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-attachment: fixed;
           background-position: center;
           background-size: 250px; 


       }

  <style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo necesidad de insertar la imagen como fondo si al contenedor de todos modos le vas a colocar un color para rellenarlo.

Dicho lo anterior puedes:

- Crear un `section` y dentro de este integrar mediante `img` la imagen deseada
- Darle un color y alto al contenedor
- Al mismo contenedor hacer que sus elementos internos sean flexibles y asi poder desplazar la imagen
- Darle un ancho y alto definido a la imagen

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          margin: 0;
        }
        .contenedor-imagen {
          background-color: black;
          min-height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }
        img {
          width: 250px;
          height: 250px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="contenedor-imagen">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="">
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! era justo lo que necesitaba, aun estoy empezando en este mundo asi que me queda mucho por aprender!

Answer (score 0):

intentaste solo poner

```
background: url('img/imagen.png'), #000000;
```

a se indica que agregues la imagen y aparte los colores

Comment: Lo probé, pero al parecer el background-color se superponía a la imagen, aun asi gracias por tu respuesta!